# Background change with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu that is using jQuery plugin to change the content of the div on the main page, all seems to be working fine till here, further from here I just want to change the background image of the site with each content.

I have the following markup in my page:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a id="home" href="/" class="switcher">
      <li class="link">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a id="wid" class="switcher">
      <li>Content One</li>
    </a>
    <a id="srv" class="switcher">
      <li>Content Two</li>
    </a>
    <a id="cnt" class="switcher">
      <li>Content three</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And I have written the following jQuery code in my js file:

```
$("nav a").click(function () {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../../Content/img/ ' + (this).id + '.jpg)').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

But this whole thing is not working, I have search over but from that information I think my code is OK which of course it’s not. What mistake am I making?

Comment: @Iznogood Nope. It won't work. Either, `this.id` or `$(this).prop("id")`.

Comment: Did you wrap that in a DOM ready function ?

Comment: i think not, can you exlpain a bit more what you are asking?

Comment: @adeneo I did that now and its working :D Thankyou pretty stupid mistake.. if you can post your comment as answer so i coudl mark it. :)

Comment: It's OK, give the points to Ispuk below, at least for effort ?

Comment: @adeneo eheh thanks, np man ;)

Comment: @adeneo, IMHO, that's not ok.  Shouldn't the points and checkmark go to the _correct_ answer?  Otherwise, how does any of this help others?  At the very least, the check-marked answer should be edited to make note of the actual solution.

Comment: @Sparky672 - It was edited, that's why I suggested just accepting it.

Comment: @adeneo, no worries but your timing is a bit off; it was edited only _after_ I made the suggestion to edit it.  I've even given a +1 since then. ;-)

Comment: @Sparky672 - Actually it was edited to include the DOM ready function before I posted the comment regarding accepting it as an answer, which would be before you suggested the edit, but who cares?

Comment: @adeneo, I see now we're talking about two different things.  I just wanted the answer to clearly point out which part was the actual fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do

```
$(function(){
    $("nav a").click(function() {
        $('body')
          .css('background-image', 'url(../../Content/img/' + (this).id + '.jpg)')
          .fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

so you just forgot the Document Ready part:

```
$(function(){

//put your code here

});
```

Comment: @VisioN you too can't understand where (this).id comes from? :D

Comment: i tryed guessing it was a attr() value :P

Comment: Thankyou for the answer ispuk, it worked plus i jsut had to add the `DOM ready function` around it. :)

Comment: @Maven you're welcome, it could happen sometimes are really stupid problems :D

Comment: In order to be most helpful to others, please edit answer to make note of the part(s) that ultimately solved it.  Thanks.